# Self deleting form button

Tags: php, javascript, html, comments, form-submit

So to begin, I'm fairly new to coding. Right now i'm working on a website that will be making sales through paypal, the issue is, however, that almost every item that will be on sale is unique, and once one sale goes through, I don't want to give the option for people to make a duplicate purchase after the item is already gone. The way paypal works with their buttons is when you select their "buy now" option you are one way or another forwarded to their site with check out options, and getting this far doesn't necessarily mean they will make the purchase, but for my purposes i'll assume they will.
So what i would like to do is make it so that once the buy now button is selected, it automatically  itself off the page or otherwise disappears so users going to or returning to that page can no longer see it. I'm pretty sure this is somehow possible in php or javascript but i'd much rather prefer a php solution, or even an html solution if somehow possible. Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: well since this is paypal, you'll have to work with their API to know whether or not an item has been purchased. You'll probably need to start there. However, I think this question might be too broad since you don't have any actual code to show yet. I would start by googling the paypal API and look into cookies as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your basic assumption that as soon as they hit "Buy Now" they have bought the item, you would need to store some values in a persistent datastore, such as a database or a flat file. Then, depending on what you choose, you can use code similar to the following to hide the button:

```
if ( hasItemBeenBought( itemId ) )
{
    echo "Looks like you missed out :(";
} else {
    echo "<button>Buy Now</button>"; // Replace with PayPal specific button
}
```

I have to agree with Stacey's comment though, this question is rather broad to just have a simple answer. PHP is stateless and won't remember anything that a previous user has done which is why you'll often find it as part of a *AMP stack (Apache, MySql & PHP).

A nice comprehensive article can be found [here](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/php/persist.htm) which talks about Cookies and Database Persistance.

Comment: thank you, that is what i was looking for, though now i have to figure out how a database works, thank you